# nginx auth_basic "Restricted" prompting login on every request

Tags: http, authentication, nginx

I've set up a simple nginx server, configured the location block to point to the respective directories I want served, and setup basic authentication using the auth_basic module.

However, ***my server requests username : password credentials on every single page request under the location block***, even after providing them multiple times to different pages under the location block, including the root location directory.

How can I configure it to store the authentication? Is this an nginx issue or a browser / request headers issue?

Here is the nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;

    location /path/to/dir {
        alias /var/www/dir/;
        index   index.html index.htm;
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Running nginx 1.4.6 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Is your login/password working? It seems like a browser bug, because it is the responsability of your browser to send http auth for each requests. This is stored in the browser, associated with the domain name. Do you use several domain names?

Comment: You can use the Network Monitor of Firefox (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) to inspect the individual HTTP requests. It should show if/how the authorization headers are sent (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). Your configuration looks correct, though.

Answer (score 12):

The problem in my case was that one of the API calls that was called by JavaScript on page load was returning 401. This seemed to reset browser auth state for the page.

Comment: How have you overcome with this issue?

Comment: Exact same problem. Image load returned 401 and triggered the basic auth. Super annoying.

Comment: Thank you. For me, this was a missing favicon.ico.

Answer (score 4):

HTTP authentication information is stored on your browser cache, and should only be requested again if the authentication fails or it's from a different realm (in `auth_basic "Restricted";` it's *Restricted*).

Your configuration is fine, considering your password is correct and Nginx user has read access to the password file (case in which it'll always fail — but send an error message at the log file indicating this error). This is the most probable reason, mainly if you have only one location with authentication.

Another possible reason is having multiple `auth_basic` directives and they use different realms or passwords. This is the same for application-generated `WWW-Authenticate` headers (say, if your backend application requests for HTTP authentication in addition to Nginx). When there's a different realm or a password fails, your browser will request it again. No browser that I know of stores authentication per URL, it's always a combination of realm+hostname.

If you do need different realms or passwords on different locations, make sure they don't overlap for a single page (for example, if you use a different password for your assets: images, styles or javascript). Or use different hosts — the password would be requested once for each host/realm combination, though.

**Update**

It's unusual to use `0.0.0.0` as a `server_name` — `listen 80;` already makes your server to listen to all interfaces/IP addresses.

Use `server_name _;` in case you mean to use any request host.